# Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates using PHP OAuth extension

Tags: php, oauth, ssl-certificate

I'm using PHP OAuth extension to make a call to the Tradeking API. When I make the exact call as in here, https://developers.tradeking.com/documentation/php

I'm getting the exception

> Exception caught! Response: making the request failed (Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates)

Why this is happening and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The OAuth extension uses curl to make the request. By default CURL will generally verify the SSL certificate to see if its valid an issued by an accepted CA. To do this, curl uses a bundled set of CA certificates.

You can either disable the SSL checks (`$oauth->disableSSLChecks()`). Or ensure that you have a current version of curl. [More information](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html) on curl certification verification.

Answer (score 7):

The right solution is checking the server TIME. If it is wrong SSL doesn't work fine.

Comment: Ah-ha!  This was it (at least for me)!  To fix this, I issued a `sudo service ntpd restart`.  Note that if your clock is too far off, you have to tweak ntpd to get it to update.  To do so, add `tinker panic 0` to the beginning of `/etc/ntp.conf` (must be the first line) (http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1006427)

Comment: Thanks, the clock on my VM was a week behind.