# How to show website and get content using PHP cURL?

Tags: php, curl

I need to show a website and get some content. For this purpose, I tried PHP cURL and run in localhost but the result is not getting. Currently, the result is getting `bool(false)`.

**index.php**

```
$url = "https://www.test-data.de/test/data?_ts=4664397-1478603498594&Command=start";
//use curl to get html content
function getUrlContent($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    return ($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300) ? $data : false;
}

$results                             = getUrlContent($url);
var_dump($results);
```

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` just after starting `<?php`. Also did you get any error? check once with `file_get_contents()`also.

Comment: add an `echo curl_error($ch)` and check what is the problem.

Comment: Please check curl error with `echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);`

Comment: So what's the actual result of the cURL request?  If the external server is returning an error, there's nothing we can do about that.

Comment: `if($errno = curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
}`  add this to your function

Comment: you got an error :- `13string(43) "cURL error (6):
 Couldn't resolve host name"`

Comment: @Anant, I didn't get error like `13string(43) "cURL error`

Comment: just check the code from here:- https://eval.in/673997  (not output)

Comment: @Anant, I just tried your code now error is showing `string(85) "cURL error (60): Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates" `

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566864/peer-certificate-cannot-be-authenticated-with-known-ca-certificates-using-php-oa

Comment: @Anant, Thanks for the link. I have added `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);` then result is showing like `string(1963) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Tue, 08 Nov 2016 12:16:57 GMT Server: Apache Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT Pragma: no-cache Cache-Control: no-cache,must-revalidate Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8 Content-Length: 1675 Vary: Accept-Encoding X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff `. Do you know why page is not showing?